# CSS opacity and background color

Tags: css, opacity

I'm using the following CSS code on my linked images:

```
a img:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: #f00;
}
```

The idea is that when a user hovers over an image, this will be slightly tinted with red. The browser though seems to ignore the "background: #f00;" property.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work as you are having image, so you need to have an overlay element, probably a div

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UyjyV/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://images.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    top: 0;
}

.wrap:hover .overlay {
    background: rgba(250, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Note: You should have a positioned relative container, else your absolute positioned div will run out in the wild, moreover, you can remove `display: inline-block;` and provide respective height and width to the container element, see to it that it sticks to your image, alternatively you can also use transitions for smooth effect

For transition you need to modify the class like this

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    top: 0;
    transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
}
```

[**Demo Transition**](http://jsfiddle.net/UyjyV/1/)